# Is there a bridge to use log4j2 api to call log4j1?

Tags: log4j, log4j2

We know that there's a log4j-1.2-api package which enables us to use log4j1 api to call log4j2.

I'm wondering if there's also a bridge provides forward compatibility. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think so. Log4j 1.x has reached end of life as well. What is your requirement to have such 2.x to 1.x bridge ?

Comment: @RajindRuparathna Thanks for your response. We are considering about migrating our service to log4j2, but worried about affecting our customers who are still using log4j1.